# Is the new question's up-vote policy on SO coming to unix.stackexchange.com?

Tags: discussion, questions, votes, policy, up-votes

The value of an up-vote on questions have recently been changed on Stackoverflow.com, here is the [acticle](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/11/13/were-rewarding-the-question-askers/) with the details (now an up-vote on a question have the same rep value as an up-vote on an answer)

Is this policy coming to unix.stackexchange.com and other sites ?

Comment: AFAIK, that change is in effect on U&L now.

Comment: People have also retroactively been awarded new badges, especially mortarboard, based on the recalculation of their rep gains.

Answer (score 5):

That change was made network-wide, not just on SO. It's not obvious from the blog post, but there is a hint (emphasis mine):

> We’re recalculating reputation for every Stack Overflow *and Stack
>   Exchange* individual based on this change.

One obvious indication of it being network-wide was the sudden awarding of a number of "Yearling" badges ([Why am I getting so many "yearling" badges today?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/338168/270345)).

---

(Except maybe Area 51, because that's an older code base - see [Does the question reputation increase apply to Area 51?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/338243/270345))